# dart flutter : Debug window message?

Tags: dart, flutter

I get the following message repeatedly in the debug window. The App is run from the phone and it is working just as expected. But the message says it cannot find method. Will it be problem later?

```
I/dalvikvm(21495): Could not find method android.content.Context.createDeviceProtectedStorageContext, referenced from method android.support.v4.content.ContextCompat.createDeviceProtectedStorageContext
W/dalvikvm(21495): VFY: unable to resolve virtual method 625: Landroid/content/Context;.createDeviceProtectedStorageContext ()Landroid/content/Context;
D/dalvikvm(21495): VFY: replacing opcode 0x6e at 0x0006
I/dalvikvm(21495): Could not find method android.content.Context.getCodeCacheDir, referenced from method android.support.v4.content.ContextCompat.getCodeCacheDir
W/dalvikvm(21495): VFY: unable to resolve virtual method 631: Landroid/content/Context;.getCodeCacheDir ()Ljava/io/File;
D/dalvikvm(21495): VFY: replacing opcode 0x6e at 0x0006
I/dalvikvm(21495): Could not find method android.content.Context.getColor, referenced from method android.support.v4.content.ContextCompat.getColor
W/dalvikvm(21495): VFY: unable to resolve virtual method 632: Landroid/content/Context;.getColor (I)I
D/dalvikvm(21495): VFY: replacing opcode 0x6e at 0x0006
```

Comment: Are you sure these messages are caused by your application?

Comment: It happens when I'm testing the App, especially when it accesses the gallery using the Image Picker plugin for Flutter. So I cannot say for sure what is causing these debug messages. I'm using a Samsung phone, OS Android 4.2.2 (Jelly Bean).

Comment: You are probably using an outdated version of android.support, and it says it cannot find these functions in the library. As you are using 4.2.2 it is probably the case.